# How to limit number of lines in a TextBox and split the lines to strings?

Tags: arrays, powershell, textbox, multiline

How can I achieve that the input of the TextBox with multilines is only possible to a specific number of lines e.g. 10 lines only.
Further I want to get the input of each line and write each line to a separate variable to work later with this variables. It would be nice if the user gets a messagebox with warning that only 10 lines are possible.
Any help would be appreciated

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

#Assembly PresentationFramework wird geladen
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen' #Formstartposition Zentrum
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,400)
$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point((110),(90))
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(288,150)
$textBox.TabIndex = 0
$textBox.Multiline =$true

$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: in  a compiled program I would respond to each keystroke on the textbox and if it's a CR / LF count it as a line and reject any keystrokes caused more than 10 of them to appear.  Not sure how you wire up an event handler in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Get Line count on the event of **TextChanged**.

2.Turn the **iList** into a **ArrayList**.

3.Get the difference from max line to current line count.

4.Remove the range from the **ArrayList**.

5.Set the content of the Textbox to the **Arraylist**

6.Set the curser to end of textbox.

```
$TextboxMaxLines = 10
$textBox.Add_TextChanged({
    If($textBox.Lines.Count -gt $TextboxMaxLines){
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$AL = $textBox.Lines
        [int]$LC = ($textBox.Lines.Count - $TextboxMaxLines)
        $Al.RemoveRange($TextboxMaxLines, $LC)
        $textbox.Lines = $AL
        $textbox.SelectionStart = ($textbox.Text.Length)
        $textbox.SelectionLength = 0
    }
})
```